# How to randomly choose from a list of questions or choose from a list of values in Google Forms

Tags: google-forms

I need to do a transit survey and I've been researching how to do this with no luck. Your help would really be appreciated.

I have questions where I give them a choice between 2 trains (A & B) each with 4 variables that I want to change for each respondent. Now I would use an Orthogonal Array to decide the values of those 4 variables but can't figure out how to change them in the form.

Somehow I need the form to populate a different set of numbers for each respondent upon page load. I understand from reading here that the corresponding spreadsheet would only change every time someone submits the form but its better than nothing. The question itself would stay the same (a multiple choice, simple train A or train B?) but the values would change. Answers would remain the same as well. Extra kudos if you know a way to do that but the values change in a boxish flashcard like illustration to better present the scenario for each.

Please walk me through this as I have no coding experience.